# Decomposition group of $G_{K,S}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, galois-theory, galois-representations

Let $K$ be a number field and fix a prime $p$. Let S be a finite set of places of $K$ containing the places above $p$ and the infinite places. Let $G_{K,S}$ be the absolute Galois group of the maximal extension of $K$ in a fixed algebraic closure of $K$ unramified outside $S$.

1) Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime of $K$ above $p$. Then what is meant by the decomposition group of $G_{K,S}$ at $\mathfrak{p}$, and is it equal to the decomposition group of $G_K$ at $\mathfrak{p}$? $\mathfrak{p}$ is not a place of the maximal extension unramified outside $S$, so I do not know how to make sense out of this.

2) Let further $\rho: G_{K,S}\to GL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ be a continuous absolutely irreducible representation. For $v$ a place not in $S$, how is $\rho(Frob_v)$ (or rather its trace) well-defined, where $Frob_v\in G_{K,S}$ is a Frobenius element? I am not assuming any unramifiedness, and again the question is how to make sense of $v$ as a place of the maximal extension unramified outside $S$.

Comment: Is there a typo here? As written $G_{K, S}$ doesn't depend on $S$, and "the maximal extension of K in a fixed algebraic closure of K" is the whole of that fixed alg closure. Do you mean to define $G_{K, S}$ as the maximal extension *unramified outside S* inside that fixed alg closure? That would be the usual notation.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Yes, sorry, I forgot to write the condition “unramified outside $S$”.

Answer (score 2):

(1) "*The* decomposition group at $\mathfrak{p}$" is not well defined on the nose as a subgroup of $G_{K, S}$. It depends on a choice of a prime above $\mathfrak{p}$ in $K^S$ (the maximal extension unramified outside $S$). However, any two such primes are in the same $G_{K, S}$-orbit, so their decomposition groups are conjugate in $G_{K, S}$. So if you're intending to (for instance) analyse the restriction of a $G_{K, S}$-representation to a decomposition group of a prime above $\mathfrak{p}$, then it doesn't matter which prime above $\mathfrak{p}$ you pick.

(2) You write "I am not assuming any unramifiedness..." -- but you are, because you're assuming $v$ is not in $S$. If $w$ is a choice of prime of $K^S$ above $v$, then $(K^S)_w / K_v$ is unramified and the decomposition group of $w$ in $K^S / K$ is (topologically) generated by a uniquely determined Frobenius element. This element depends on $w$, but its conjugacy class does not. So $\rho(Frob_v)$ is well-defined up to conjugation in $GL_2$, and hence has a uniquely defined trace.

(As an aside: among these two questions, which fairly elementary, you have smuggled in a seriously deep question! You ask if the decomposition groups of a prime above $\mathfrak{p}$ in $G_K$ and $G_{K, S}$ are the same. If $K = \mathbf{Q}$ and $|S| \ge 2$ this is indeed true, but this is a rather recent theorem, proved in 2009 by [Chenevier and Clozel](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2009-22-02/S0894-0347-08-00617-6/) using sophisticated techniques from the Langlands program.)

Comment: Thanks. I am still a bit confused. What is $G_{K,S}$ for you here? Is it $Gal(\bar{K}/K^S)$ or $Gal(K^S/K)$? I was assuming the first case, but maybe it should be the second, e.g. in the second case saying that a representation of $G_{K,S}$ is unramified outside $S$ seems more natural than in the first case. I guess in the first case for writing $\rho(Frob_v)$ you need your rep to be trivial on the inertia of $v$ (or rather of any prime in $K^S$ above $v$).

Comment: $G_{K, S} = Gal(K^S / K)$ is the standard notation. (If you misunderstood it as $Gal(\bar{K} / K^S)$ then that might explain some of your confusion.)